# Understanding Basic Python Logic and Flow of Operations (a, b = b, a+b)

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the code provided on the Python.org tutorial in section 3.2

```
a, b = 0, 1
>>> while b < 10:
...     print(b)
...     a, b = b, a+b
```

The code above results in the sequence as follows:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Why do the numbers appear vertically and not horizontally like a print statement generally does?  I know you can force the numbers to appear horizontally but want to understand why that is not the default.
2. Most importantly, how is the python logic working?  I understand its the fibonacci sequence but you're only asking the code to print "b".  It should just print a+b over and over again, should it not (resulting in 1 being printed over and over again)?  I don't understand how the logic within python progresses the sequence.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: For 1. `print()` by default adds a new line character. 2. is simply assignment, `b` is assigned to `a` and `a+b` is assigned to `b`, RHS operations are conducted before the assignment

Comment: Think og `a, b = b, a+b` as `(a,b) = (b, a+b)`. That is assigning the pair on the right hand side to the pair on the left hand side. This will result in `a` being assigned the value of `b`, and `b` the value of `a+b`. The key is that the righthand side is evaluated before either of the assignments.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you think it should print the same number each time. It prints the value of b, then assigns b a new value. Is that not clear?

Comment: Thanks all for your prompt replies, I'm brand new to python so this is all very new.  

when you say print(b), shouldn't that only print whatever value b was assigned?  why does it take anything related to a into account?

Comment: @NRF It prints `b`, but the loop keeps updating `b` with new values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python print statement by default generates a newline after each print. 
This causes each printed item to appear on its own line. If you print a literal newline, you get two blank lines:

```
>>> print "\n"


>>>
```

> Most importantly, how is the python logic working? I understand its
>   the fibonacci sequence but you're only asking the code to print "b".
>   It should just print a+b over and over again, should it not (resulting
>   in 1 being printed over and over again)?

This line:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

evaluates the expressions `b` and `a+b`. If b=1 and a=0, then this results in the tuple `(1, 1)`. That tuple is then split into its two components and assigned respectively to the variables `a` and `b`. So at the end of the first iteration, a and b each get the value 1. This is ultimately equivalent to the successive operations

```
tmp = b
b = a + b
a = tmp
```

but notice that here we have to create a temp variable to hold the original value of b. This is because the one-liner evaluates both of the expressions on its right-hand side before it assigns to the variables named on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code would be quite simple if you used parentheses. The code a,b is a tupel:
`(a,b)=(0,1)`
Let's interpret the code line per line:

```
While b<10: #b=1
    print(b) #output:1
    (a,b) = (a,a+b) # a=1, b=1
```

Now the next iteration:

```
While b<10: #b=1
    print(b) #output:1
    (a,b) = (a,a+b) # a=1, b=2
```

And the next:

```
While b<10: #b=1
    print(b) #output:2
    (a,b) = (a,a+b) # a=2, b=3
```

And so on....
You will get
1
1
2
3
5
8
But each number in a separate line because print function add '\n'. So the output is "vertical".

Comment: With this code `a,b = (1,2)`, `a and b` are the unpacked values of the tuple `(1,2)` this also work with `a, b, *c = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` where `a=1, b = 2 and c = (3,4,5)`. The same thing will happen with lists too.

Comment: Also, it's called `tuple` not `tupel` see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the spelling mistake. You remind me of my Algebra teacher, Always focusing​ on what most important.